# AngularJS 1.5 : accessing component definition

Tags: angularjs, components

Is there a way to get a component definition?

I have a service to open dialog and I would like to do something like this :

```
angular
    .component('main', {
       //...
       controller: ['dialogService', function(dialogService) {
           dialogService.open({
               component: 'ask'
           });
       }]
    })
    .component('ask', {
        //...
    });
```

For this, I need to access the component definition.

I could `$compile` something like `'<'+componentName+'/>'` but I would like to know when the component instantiation is done.

Comment: Do you mean when the component has been instantiated in your model or after it's finished instantiating in a state/route where you use it?

Comment: What "component instantiated in a model" means ? I would like that my modal/dialog service is able to open a new dialog with a component as content (like the component router does with ng-outlet directive). But I need to know when the component is loaded (template loaded, etc) to trigger an event when the modal is ready.